# How do I sort a list in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, python-3.3

How can I sort the list present in the dictionary:

```
fourB={"James":[10,11,9]}
```

I will have multiple entries but I want to be able to sort the list of integers out for each one of them. How can I do that? Thanks!Any help will be appreciated. :)

Comment: `fourB["James"].sort()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should iterate over the keys and sort their values:

```
for k in fourB.keys():
    fourB[k].sort()
```

Comment: This is needlessly inefficient--see my answer.

Comment: @JohnZwinck In what way?

Comment: @thefourtheye: this solution iterates over the keys, and looks them up in the dict.  The lookup is not free, and is totally unnecessary, because you can iterate over the values instead.  My answer demonstrates this.

Answer (score 6):

```
for numbers in fourB.values():
    numbers.sort()
```

The above is better than iterating over the `keys()` followed by indexing into `fourB`, because here you avoid the `dict` lookup.

If you love one-liners, here's one:

```
map(list.sort, fourB.values())
```

But take note if there are many keys in the dict, as this will return a list of `[None]*len(fourB.values())` which is immediately discarded--and that's not optimally efficient.  I'd stick with the obvious loop version for this reason and also for readability.